# Satchmo Installation error on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python-2.7, satchmo

I am new to web development and tried installing the satchmo eCommerce framework by following step by step instructions mentioned [here](http://docs.satchmoproject.com/en/latest/new_installation.html).

When I finished the installation, I am getting error:

> 'module' object has no attribute 'find_template_source'

I have made sure that I am not using any custom template loaders.

I would help any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after trial and error and found & I would like to share if anyone faces same issue.

I had to install in order to make it working:

> sudo pip install django-caching-app-plugins